# How should release management be structured for an agile Professional Services department?

Tags: process, release-management

**Background**

Professional Services departments provide add-on services to customers of a product.

A lot of these projects are small (4-10 hours) and need to be turned around quickly. Additionally, these are important projects as they are enhancements that customers rely on for their business.

**Some challenges are:**

1. There is a good amount of rework or feature changes as customers often change their mind or make tiny additional request. Aside from the obvious that this is a mangement issue (managing scope creep etc.), the fact remains that often there are minor tweaks that need to be implemented after the project is "live".
2. Sometimes something breaks for whatever reason and issues need to be handled with expedience. Again, these are in-production processes that customers rely on.

**Currently, our release management is very ad hoc:**

1. Engineers manage the projects from soup to nuts, including scoping, customer relationships, code development, production deployment, and project support (for any subsequent issues).
2. We have dev servers and we have production servers. The servers exist on-site in a server farm. They are not backed up ever, and they have no redundancy because they are not in the colo - they kind of get second class service from operations.
3. They Engineers have full root(linux)/admin(windows) access to the dev and prod servers. They develop on the dev servers, and when the project is ready, deploy to prod (basically, just copy the files up). When issues come up, they just work directly on the servers.
4. We use svn for source control but it's basically just check out to dev, work on the project, check in as necessary, and deploy to prod just by copying files up to the server.

**The problem:**

The problem is basically number 2 above. The servers are not treated with the same reverence by operations that our product servers (in the colo) are treated. We need the servers to be first class citizens for operations. However their proposal is to put them in the colo, which makes them untouchable. If we do that, we will need to go through operations to get projects deployed. Basically it will be the same arduous and painful process that the product engineers go through when releasing an update to our software product.

This would take away all our agility in responding to these tiny projects and the issues that arise that need immediate attention.

**The question**

How should we solve this problem?
Should we put the servers in colo and just work with the formal release process?
How should this situation be handled?

Any help making this question better is welcome!

Comment: Is this question really so boring?>

Comment: Colocation center...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colocation_centre

Answer (score 0):

> The servers exist on-site in a server farm. They are not backed up
>   ever, and they have no redundancy because they are not in the colo -
>   they kind of get second class service from operations.

So you want these servers to be self-serviceable by your PS engineers, yet have good redundancy, backup etc without having to go through formal ops processes. Can't you move them from the on-site server farm to the cloud (ec2 or other)? btw, #3 & #4 are accidents waiting to happen but that is not material to the main question here.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but sounds very similar to our company in that production team requires a lot of small changes.

I'm having a hard time understanding the question but I'll attempt an answer.

You should not place development servers in the colo because it will slow down your development process.  If operations is not able to give you the support you need in development could you designate a developer or bring on someone that can support your teams needs when it comes to server management/requirements.  Ideally a build engineer, release manager, or even say a QA resource.  Unfortunately it sounds like a political management issue.  In that case you need to clearly layout you issues and address them with management.  If I completely missed the mark let me know.